# Merging alike results in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

So I have 2 tables. The first table contains claims. Each claim has a unique rID. Each claim can have multiple entries attached to it. The entries also have error codes attached to it. Every claim can only have 1 error code that, again, is listed in the entry(ies). What I'm trying to do is Select my claims based on errorCode. The returned result would look something like this:

```
rID  |   errorCode  | total amount for error Code  | total amount of claims that have the error code.
```

My current results are listing each unique claim but showing me a claim for each error code with the associated amount. It should be consolidating the amounts and error code count in to 1 column. How can I accomplish this? Here's the code I'm currently using and also a snapshot of what it looks like in SQL with my results. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  rID, 
  (SELECT TOP 1 errorCode FROM entries e WHERE e.rID=c.rID) as ec, 
  round((SELECT SUM(refundDue) FROM entries WHERE rID=c.rID),0) as amount 

  FROM claims c WHERE status='closed' AND c.auditorID='101' AND (c.dateon >= '20191018' AND c.dateon < '20191025') ORDER BY ec asc
```

[image: current sql results]

Based on this image, the results should be something like this

```
ECTotal   |  EC   |  amount
_______     _____   ________
   1         AI      600.00
   2         CI      4494.00
  10         CL      12654.00
   3         DN      11138.00
   2         RB      893.00
   3         RT      15256.00
   1         WA      567.00
   1         WP      2488.00
   1         WT      2378.00
```

Comment: Got some sample data, table definitions and desired output? [mcve]

Comment: just added desired output based i'm what i'm currently outputting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need group by . . ?

**untested**

```
SELECT count(distinct c.rid) ECTotal, e.errorcode ec,
   round(SUM(refundDue),0) as amount
FROM claims c
inner join entries e on e.rid=c.rid
WHERE c.status='closed'
   AND c.auditorID='101'
   AND (c.dateon >= '20191018' AND c.dateon < '20191025')
GROUP BY e.errorcode
ORDER BY e.errorcode asc
```

Comment: dude... that's so close.... looks like the amounts are added up just fine but the ectotal count is off... (2) AI, (2) CI, (31) CL... etc. all those are wrong

Comment: Maybe try `count(distinct c.rid)` instead?

Comment: that did it! Dude, you are amazing. Care to explain all this to me? My SQL understanding is basic so i'm lost here. Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to do a little research.  This is somewhat basic SQL.  You'll want to research `join` to understand that part.  Then you'll research `group by` to understand grouping and aggregation (this allows for summing the refundDue).  Count is fairly straight forward -- the original answer counted all of the entries in the entries table for each error code (there are multiple entries per claim).  Since instead you wanted the count of claims for each error code, we changed it to count the distinct c.rid (counting how many different claims).